# Does PDF contain high-level layout system for text?

Tags: pdf, layout

I'm just curious to know how text is handled in PDF under the hood. Does it contain high-level layout system like HTML that does things like breaking paragraphs into lines, or does it only support low-level operations like putting each characters at an absoulte position?

Comment: The latter. The PDF writer positions everything. That's why readers cannot easily adjust a PDF to different screen sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PDF, text is represented by Glyphs. Individual glyphs can be positioned exactly on a page, or a sequence of glyphs can be laid out, following some rules for spacing between them. There is no concept of words, lines, paragraphs, blocks or anything similar. The PDF specification does allow some descriptive information (like the number of columns on a page), but generally speaking such information is not reliable.